# LiveData not emitting new values after two searches

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, viewmodel

So, I have an app that has a `SearchView`, each time I search for a cocktail it refreshes the list with that cocktail, this works with the first and second search, after doing it for the third time the livedata is not emitting again and hence I cant see the loading if the new searched data

### View

```
  private fun setupObservers(){
        viewModel.fetchTragosList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { result ->
            when(result){
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    rv_tragos.adapter = MainAdapter(requireContext(), result.data.toMutableList(),this)
                }
                is Resource.Failure -> {
                    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Error: ${result.exception}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    private fun setupSearchView(){
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object:SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                viewModel.setTrago(query!!)
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }
        })
    }
```

### ViewModel

```
class MainViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor (private val repo:Repo):ViewModel(){

    private val tragosData = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun setTrago(tragoName:String){
        tragosData.value = tragoName
    }

    init {
        setTrago("margarita")
    }


    val fetchTragosList = tragosData.distinctUntilChanged().switchMap { nombreTrago ->
        liveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(Resource.Loading())
            try{
                emit(repo.getByName(nombreTrago))
            }catch (e: Exception){
                emit(Resource.Failure(e))
            }
        }
    }
```

### Repo

```
override suspend fun getTragoByName(nombreTrago: String): Resource<List<Drink>> {
        return Resource.Success(webService.getTragoByName(nombreTrago).drinksList)
    }
```

So what happens is that I search 1 time and it works, I search for the second time and it works, when I search again it stops emitting and I cant seem to have the new data I'm looking for, if there is a wrong name that is not found it does also not return anything when clicking the search button.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Add some logs to find out which methods aren't being called